# Stomp over WebSocket in React Native

Tags: react-native

Has anyone tried using Stomp protocol over the WebSocket implementation in react native? We are using Stomp for the web application, and it would be great if I did not have build a separate back end for the web and mobile applications.

I haven't found a good way to integrate Stomp with the react native Web Sockets.

Comment: You can always use the Stomp implementations of Android/iOS and hook up your code with the JS side.

Comment: https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped the latest typescript / js [@stomp/stompjs](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs) STOMP client into a React HOC, making use of SockJS library to simulate the websocket. [feel free to check it out](https://github.com/loming/react-stompjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
var connected =false;
var socket ='';
var stompClient = '';
const  send = (param)=> {
      let send_message =param;
      if (stompClient && stompClient.connected) {
        const msg = { name: send_message };
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", JSON.stringify(msg), {});
      }
}
const connect =()=> {
      socket = new SockJS("your endpoint");
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect(
        {},
        frame => {
          connected = true;
          stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", tick => {
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          connected = false;
        }
      );
 }
const disconnect =()=> {
      if (stompClient) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
      }
      connected = false;
}
const tickleConnection =()=> {
      connected ? disconnect() : connect();
}
```

Comment: param is a local variable doesn't use param by default let send_message ='';

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: can you give a bit more of context of what the solution is doing. Its difficult to understand at this point. Thanks and welcome :)